# How to fetch the results from two tables based on mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

Here i have two tables, i want get the results from this two tables.i tried lot but i am unable to get the exact results can you please any help me, i am using this application in codeiniter.

First Table

> new_staff

```
staff_id              firstName        Mobile          userType

  1                  Soupranjali       9986125566       Teacher
  2                  Sujata            8553880306       Teacher
```

Second Table

> new_student

```
student_id           first_Name        fatherMobile        user_type

  1                  janarthan         8553880306         Student
  2                  Santanu           8277904354         Student
  3                  Sarvan            8553880306         Student
```

here **8553880306**  both table this mobile number is present, so want get to the both table results

> Expected Results

```
    {
  "status": "Success",
  "Profile": [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType" : "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "firstName": "janarthan",
      "user_type" : "Student"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "3",
      "firstName": "Sarvan",
      "user_type" : "Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

So tried like this but i unable to get the answer, so please anyone help me,

> my model

```
  public function android_memberList($mobile)
    {
        $this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType');
        $this->db->from('new_staff');
        $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
        $query1 = $this->db->get();

        # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
        $result_new_staff = $query1->result_array(); 

        $this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.first_Name, new_student.user_type');
        $this->db->from('new_staff');
        $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
        $query2 = $this->db->get();

        # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
        $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 

        $final_result=array_merge($result_new_staff,$result_new_student);

        $result["status"] = "Success";
        $result["Profile"] = $final_result;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

**Based on my query it is returning the output like this, but this is not my expected json fomat**

- Here staff_id and firstName is coming two two time,actual result it has to to come one time only,any one see my expected results and tell me solution

> my result

```
 {
  "status": "Success",
  "Profile": [
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType": "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "staff_id": "2",
      "firstName": "Sujata",
      "userType": "Teacher"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "first_Name": "janarthan",
      "user_type": "Student"
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "first_Name": "Santanu",
      "user_type": "Student"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have to use 2 select queries and then marge both results in on array. only this us can get what you want because JOIN gives result of combination of both tables and here given mobile number matches with two columns in student table and one in teacher table.

Comment: You could use `UNION` / `UNION ALL` if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Group by in select query

```
public function android_memberList($mobile)
{
    $this->db->select('new_staff.staff_id, new_staff.firstName, new_staff.userType');
    $this->db->from('new_staff');
    $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
$this->db->group_by('new_staff.staff_id');
    $query1 = $this->db->get();

    # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result_new_staff = $query1->result_array(); 

    $this->db->select('new_student.student_id, new_student.first_Name, new_student.user_type');
    $this->db->from('new_staff');
    $this->db->join('new_student', 'new_student.fatherMobile  = new_staff.Mobile');
$this->db->group_by('new_staff.staff_id');
    $query2 = $this->db->get();

    # result_array is used to convert the data into an array
    $result_new_student = $query2->result_array(); 

    $final_result=array_merge($result_new_staff,$result_new_student);

    $result["status"] = "Success";
    $result["Profile"] = $final_result;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```